# Importing CSV files into MySql table with one column as name of CSV files

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I have 35 CSV files which I want to import to MYSQL table(say 'test'). I want to create one column in 'test' table( say 'file_name'). This column will contain name of the CSV from which data has been imported. The file names are unique IDs, that is why I want to get file name as input in the table.

Suppose I have CSV files like X1.csv, X2.CSV, X3.csv .... X35.csv. I want a column in 'test' table as 'file_name' such that 'test' table looks something like:

---

col1 -> a, b, c, d

col2 -> x, y, w, z

...
...

... ....

file_name -> X1, X1, X2, X3

---

Note: I tried to search this question on forum but I could not find any suitable solution. Also I am new to MYSQL, please help even it is a trivial thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is *exactly* what you are looking for, but at first sight, you should investigate the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'X1.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name -- Load the content of the CSV file
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'    -- assuming fields separate by ",", enclosed by "'"
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'                  -- assuming end-of-line being '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES                              -- assuming first line is a header and should be ignored
  SET file_name = 'X1';                       -- force the column `file_name` to be the name of the file
```

Please note that with such statement, each *field* will go in its own *column* of the table. And each line of the CSV data file will be loaded a *one row* in the table. This will imply that there will be several rows in the result table with the same file name. In fact one row per data line.